# Laravel Project work perfect on localhost and Response with error 500 on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-6

I'm fairly new to working with live projects.

My project runs perfectly on localhost, I deploy the exact same copy to google app engine using the  command `gcloud beta app deploy`.

My welcome page works perfectly:

[image]

As  Well as my auth pages:

[image]

straight after the auth process i get the following response:

[image]

To verify that the account has been authenticated my route url is redirecting to the dashboard:
example.com/admin/users

my app.yaml file is as follows:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: App-key
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
  SESSION_DRIVER: file

  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_DATABASE: lara
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/connection-name

  MAIL_MAILER: smtp
  MAIL_HOST: smtp.mailtrap.io
  MAIL_PORT: 2525
  MAIL_USERNAME:username
  MAIL_PASSWORD: password
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: from@example.com
  MAIL_FROM_NAME: {App-Name}
#we need this for the flex environment
beta_settings:
   # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
   cloud_sql_instances: connection-name
```

Here is my log?
[image]

This is the view it is looking for:
[image]

My routes:
[image]

Comment: What's the error in your Laravel log file? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Do you have any logs that show what is the error that generated this status 500? If you do please add them to the question so that the community can help you investigate.

Comment: I have added the logs as requested,my apologies it too this long...i had to setup and enable stack trace logs to recieve server logs. @ralemos

Comment: @DimitriMostrey do have any suggestions for this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how small things create the biggest issues, took me over 3 weeks to resolve this issue.

As I was conducting research I discovered that Google App engine is case sensitive and so here are steps I used to resolve this issue:

1st I checked my routes using `php artisan route:list` and my route is `route: admin.users.index` and my file structure was `--path: views/Admin/Users/index.blade.php` and so i change all my folders to lower-case to match the route.

Then I ran the following commands:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

Lastly I added the following script under scripts on my composer.json file:

`"post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]`

Deployed using `gcloud app deploy`

Worked like a charm.